# Approx. every hour, why does Avast pop up and "safely aborted connection on flashvd.net"?

Tags: avast

On August 5 2021, my Avast started popping up the following approx. every hour that I use my Windows laptop. I don't recognize, and have never intentionally visited, flashvd.net.

1. The snag appears to be flashvd.net. If this is a malicious website, how can I banish it?
2. How do I stop these pop ups from my Avast, without risking my computer?

[image]

Comment: https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=239139.0 to understand the website has been blacklisted. Something IS trying to connect and Avast is doing its job. The problem isn't the popup, the problem is an infected system.

Comment: How you stop is is outlined in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).  As for why the notification is being displayed, Avast is detecting that some process is attempting to visit a website that is on their blacklist, the ultimate solution is to remove that process so the behavior stops.

Comment: That the program listed is Firefox suggests that one of your extensions may well be a problem. Do you use any video downloader extensions by any chance?

Comment: @Mokubai "Do you use any video downloader extensions by any chance?" Yes! Let me review them.